# Smartd supress/change level for FAILURE PREDICTION THRESHOLD EXCEEDED

Tags: smart, drive-failure, smartctl, smartmontools

I'm using smartd to monitor drive health

It started compaining about FAILURE PREDICTION THRESHOLD EXCEEDED for one drive, but I extensively tested that drive and it's fully functional

That drive is one of many in this machine

How can I disable or change warning level for this single drive? I don't want to change it system wide, only this particular warning for this drive

Comment: Please post `smartctl -x /dev/sdX` output for this drive.